# MySql.Data.MySqlClient for C#, time expires for a large MySql table

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, database

I am using MySql.Data.MySqlClient for C# in one of my applications.

At certain point, my .net application selects, from one large MySql table, which :

- has two columns,
- one column is the primary key ( PRI, int(11), auto increment )
- other column is the column that contains some text, ( varchar(8000) )
- one example entry for this column is:

> info1=a;info2=b;cIndex=1;info4=d;info5=0.33;

just by chance, the entries on this very large table that includes the text segment "'%cIndex=1;%'" are before from the entries that includes the text segment for larger cIndex values, such as 34.

For instance:

- the entry with a column2 value of
  "info1=a;info2=b;cIndex=1;info4=d;info5=0.33"; is the 45566th entry
  on this database,
- whereas the entry with column2 value of 
  "info1=a;info2=b;cIndex=34;info4=d;info5=0.33;" is the 10,000,000th
  entry on the table.
- So basically, the entries with lower cIndex values are before from
  the entries with higher cIndex values.

Key difference for this table from my earlier applications is that, the table I am running sql statement is "very large" by my standards;

- with 2 columns
- yet 24.6 million rows.
- and with a data structure I mentioned above.

An example of the sql statement I am running from within my application is:

```
SELECT column2 FROM myLargeTable WHERE (column2 LIKE
'%info3=1;%') AND (column2 LIKE '%cIndex=0;%');
```

And, the method I am using in my c# application in order to run this query for a result is basically as follows:

```
public static string getInfoFromDb(string tbl, string col, string whr)
{

string myInfo = "error";

string sqlStr = "SELECT " + col + " from " + tbl + " " + whr + " " + " LIMIT 1 ";

MySqlConnection cn = new MySqlConnection(cstr); 
cn.Open();
try 
{
MySqlCommand co = new MySqlCommand(sqlStr, cn); 
MySqlDataReader rd = co.ExecuteReader(); 
while (rd.Read()) { myInfo = rd.GetString(col); } 
co.Dispose(); 
}

catch { /* do nothing */}
cn.Close();

return myInfo;
}
```

(So, the code is pretty much simple and it worked, for long years, for my databases where the tables sizes was much smaller at around, say, 70000+ rows)

My question is:

- my sql statement returns the correct result when it is run from the
  editor page of Toad-for-MySql, for any cIndex value - either it is a
  smaller value such as 1, or a larger value such as 34. In any case,
  the sql statement returns the correct result.
- And, expectedly, this sql statement returns the correct result when the same sql statement is run, from within my C# application this time, when the cIndex value is small such as 1, i.e. SELECT column2 FROM myLargeTable WHERE (column2 LIKE '%info3=1;%') AND (column2 LIKE '%cIndex=1;%') returns the correct result.
- But, interestingly, and this time unexpectedly, the very same sql statement returns error saying timeout expired when the same sql statement is run, from within my C# application, when the cIndex value of interest in the sql statement is larger, such as 34. i.e. SELECT column2 FROM myLargeTable WHERE (column2 LIKE '%info3=1;%') AND (column2 LIKE '%cIndex=34;%')

Any help is very much appreciated.

Thanks in advance for your time and considerations.

Comment: As an aside, for sanity & performance reasons perhaps its time to break that multiple-key-value-pairs-in-a-single-column design into a correctly  normalised single-value-in-multiple-columns design.

Comment: You are absolutely right Alex. This design, as you might agree, gave me a huge flexibility in reviewing, reconstructing, and rebuilding my c# flow (without any need to review and alter my database design) in the beginning. But now, as you suggested, the time will come to break my one-line-delimited structure into a multi-column design. But still, I am still curious why my method presented above is not working properly for this large database table and would like to have a decent answer for future problems. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that the error is due to timeout for larger tables.

So, apparently, adding this line of code into my method solved the problem:

```
co.CommandTimeout = 600; // keep this value relatively large while working with large databases
```